# Browser for one web-site only

Tags: browser

Our company of 100 people has subscribed to a cloud to-do service. Problem is working through regular browser is inconvenient and distracting.

What I want is to have a Win executable with the proper icon and name which opens as a browser without address bar (tab bar and all the buttons) and shows to-do service as a homepage.

Chromium is open-source as example, don't know but might be possible to set homepage, remove address bar and compile it.

Tried Chrome kiosk mode, but I don't exactly need blocking whole screen for users.

Or other ideas please.

Comment: Vs2015 has a few options creating applications that serve up single Web pages. I can't remember the project for off hand, but it will require some minimal programming.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way: Create a small VS project with an Internet Explorer shell.

The best way: Either doing what you mentioned or by using a Chrome (or by extension Blink) based framework like awesomium or CEF.